# Deploy Docker container to Kubernetes using yaml file

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy a docker container to Kubernetes using YAML file (local system).

Part 1: Docker container (Working fine)

- I am able to run the container and push into docker hub
- Able to access container application over a browser.

Part 2: Kubernetes (Not working)

- Wrote deployment.yaml file that includes both deployment and service
- Deployment:  It is creating pod successfully
- Service: Added service and trying to access the application over a browser but it is not working

  > Error: Site can't be reached

Docker:

- Container pushed into docker hub

  - name: $ID/tomcat-jenkins
  - version: 3

Kubernetes:

- deployment.yaml

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: jenkins
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: tomcat
      replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: tomcat
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: tomcat-jenkins
            image: $DOCKER-ID/tomcat-jenkins:3
            ports:
            - containerPort: 80
    # Service
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: jenkins
    spec:
      selector:
        app: tomcat
      ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 80
        targetPort: 80
        nodePort: 31011
      type: NodePort
```

I am not able to access the application after deploying the container in Kubenetes pod.

I'm not sure whether my deployment.yaml file contains some syntax errors.

Comment: share the output from below command

Comment: kubectl get po -owide --show-labels

Comment: Your deployment.yaml file has no syntax errors, you'd get a loading error if it had. That of course doens't mean it makes sense to kubernetes which, because it doesn't use tags, does all kinds of intransparent interpretation of the datastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are exposing the service on **NodePort** , then you can access it with the http://NodeIP:NodePort` . the value of nodeport is 31011 for the above service.

Here is the a detail [tutorail](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/) which explain exposing the service on k8s.

> ClusterIP (default) - Exposes the Service on an internal IP in the cluster. This type makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster.
>
> NodePort - Exposes the Service on the same port of each selected Node in the cluster using NAT. Makes a Service accessible from outside the cluster using :. Superset of ClusterIP.
>
> LoadBalancer - Creates an external load balancer in the current cloud (if supported) and assigns a fixed, external IP to the Service. Superset of NodePort

Comment: I am very new to Kuberntes - below is the details

External IP: 192.XX.XX.1X (Generated IP while starting up minikube)
Cluster IP: 10.110.XX.121

Tried to access the application:
192.XX.XX.1X:31011
10.110.XX.121:31011

Nothing works...

Comment: minikube  provide the following command to access the svc on browser `minikube service $SERVICE_NAME `  for your case `minikube service jenkins`

Comment: Suresh:

Tried:
    $ minikube service jenkins
      Opening kubernetes service default/jenkins in default browser...

Redirects: http://192.168.XX.XX:31011

Error: Can't connect to the Server

Not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: `kubectl get pods,svc`   hopefully the pod is up and running

Comment: Suresh, I tried to check the process:

    kubectl get pods | grep jenkins
    jenkins-8478654f4c-98n8f                1/1     Running   0          59m
    jenkins-8478654f4c-rl8gd                1/1     Running   0          59m

    kubectl get svc | grep jenkins
    jenkins                NodePort    10.110.184.121   <none>        80:31011/TCP      58m

Comment: let's try this way `kubectl exec -ti jenkins-8478654f4c-98n8f bash` and then try `curl -kv localhost:80`

Comment: If still it did not work, we can try to deploy other app , expose it and access it, As I understand we are doing fine technically

Comment: Suresh - Apologies for the late reply.
I tried to connect to the pod/container (exec - bash) and execute "curl" command

Comment: Output:

root@jenkins-8478654f4c-98n8f:/# curl -kv localhost:80
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:80/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address
* Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Comment: Hi , no worries, can you expose your Application on 8080 port ? you need to edit value in dockerfile,deployment and service

Comment: Okay - let me try that

Comment: Suresh - I updated the config as you mentioned
Dockerfile: EXPOSE 8080
Kubeneretes deployment.yaml:
- ports: container: 8080
- port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080

Comment: Curl output:
root@jenkins-8478654f4c-98n8f:/# curl -kv localhost:8080
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8080/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*

Comment: After updating Port 8080 in Dockerfile & deployment.yaml file  - I am able to connect the application over Kubernetes port

Comment: now try to access it on browser with `NodeIP:nodePort`

Comment: I am able to connect to the IP which is generated during minikube startup
"minikube" IP address is 192.XX.99.XX:31011/jenkins
Is above validation is correct ?

Comment: Suresh - Really appreciate your helpful pointers - helped me to resolve the issue

Comment: i am glad that it was helpful :)